# To search for document and then search for array element inside those document in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to make an upvote and downvote feature for my website. Here is my schema

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa639cb4add7a1c58507ac1"),
"vote" : -7,
"votedBy" : [],
"Fbid" : "109590486545309",
"imageId" : "86i1dr8apv",
"email" : "emnnevbjyo_1520686942@tfbnw.net",
"event" : "selfie",
"__v" : 0}
```

Now, what is am trying is to lookup my documents with **imageId**, and then look in the array of **votedBy** for specific voter. If the query results with some value act according to the logic of upvoting or downvoting. Here is my upvote and downvote code

```
app.get('/:id/love', (req, res) => {
console.log("Hitting");
var image_Id = req.params.id;
var fb_id = req.user.id;
var query = {
    "imageId": image_Id
}
var upvote = {
    $inc: {
        vote: 1
    },
    $push: {
        votedBy: req.user.id
    }
}

var downvote = {
    $pull: {
        votedBy: req.user.id
    },
    $inc: {
        vote: -1
    }
}
likeImformation.find({
    "imageId": image_Id
}, {
    "votedBy": fb_id
}).count(function(err, count_num){
    if(count_num===0){
        likeImformation.findOneAndUpdate(query, upvote, function (err, voted) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(404)
            } else {
                console.log("upvoted");
                res.send("upvoted");
            }
        });
    }
    else if(count_num>0){
        console.log(count_num);
        likeImformation.findOneAndUpdate(query, downvote, function (err, voted) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(404)
            } else {
                console.log("downupvoted");
                res.send("downvoted");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

The problem is I am unable to write the query, which would search for the document and then in the document search for the array element and match it with the "votedBy".

Answer (score 0):

We can write query using `and` in MongoDB

`{$and:[{
      "imageId": image_Id
}, {
    "votedBy": fb_id
}]}`

and it will work as expected